# Android Vector Drawable Intrinsic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

The VectorDrawable refers to the following:

android:width

Used to define the intrinsic width of the drawable. This
support all the dimension units, normally specified with dp.

What is meant by "intrinsic"? I thought the point of VectorDrawable was independent of size. If I don't supply the width, my app crashes. What does this value do? I'm not using it, but I have to put in a value anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intrinsic dimensions of a `VectorDrawable` specified by `android:width` and `android:height` give the drawable a *default size*.

Consider the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/example_drawable"/>
```

What size is this?

Well the `ImageView` uses `wrap_content` so it wraps to the size of the drawable. If VectorDrawables didn't have default heights and widths specified then this ImageView wouldn't make sense, it's supposed to wrap to the size of it's content, but the content doesn't have a size!

Hence `VectorDrawables` must have a default width and height. You can scale them to the size you need them to be, but if there's a situation where they're not being told from somewhere else what size they should be, they need to know what to do.

Comment: Cool. I'm telling it what size to be by my program, so in my case I guess this isn't needed. I tried to not specify, but my program crashed. If I had them, works fine. If I put in different values, no difference. Again, my case. Now that you say this matters if I use wrap_content, then that makes more sense. I haven't tried this out, but I'll mark this as correct. I'm a bit too tied up to actually test this out. TY